# How to run exe file on web server use php

Tags: php, laravel, server, exe

I have hostgator cpanel web server. And I want to run exe file on it with php. Is it possible to do that? On window computer it is possible to start a program with the help of php command exec() with command line arguments. I'm looking for a solution so that I can do the same on my web server too.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting sever running UNIX-like OS, Linux,
for example, it's not possible, you have to look for alternative binaries on that server.

Comment: That means that you have to use Linux binaries, it's different from Windows. What kind of program you trying to run from exec()?

Comment: VB. exe  i want  use php plate from my exe

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to imagine, that any hosting company would change shared-hosting server configuration to install Visual Basic compiler. I would recommend to buy virtual private server, if you need it badly, here's a link to discussion about VB over Linux: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=935610

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must understand is the difference between a web host and a dedicated server.  On a dedicated server, you do what you want whereas a shared hosting server is shared among hundreds, sometimes thousands of users.

That difference is reflected in the price and justifies severe restrictions that need to be imposed by the host to maintain a good overall service level.

That said, functions of the `exec()` and `system()` family are also available for Linux, but you won't be able to run Windows executables on Linux without additional tools such as `Wine` which certainly won't be available on a shared host.